# Using Batch files to execute multiple commands

Tags: optimization, batch-file, jpeg

I'm using jpegtran to transform jpegs in a directory to an optimized version of itself. I do this for maybe 10-15 jpegs. I already wrote a batch file that executes all the commands for every jpeg, but I was wondering if there was an approach similar to a bash script where I can say:

```
jpegtran -optimize -copy none *.jpg optsameasoriginalfilename.jpg
```

Problem is, the target file cannot be the same as the file that is being converted unless it's going to a different directory.

Is there a batch file that can do this for me? Rather than me going in the batch file I made and manually changing all the names of the source and target filenames?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what the bash script does that a batch does not?

Comment: @AlexK. The bash script would take in the * wildcard and do that command for everything that ends in .jpeg in the directory. I'm just wondering if there is an equivalent call like the * wildcard where I can execute multiple commands with just one single command.

Comment: Well `FOR %%f IN (*.JPG) DO jpegtran -optimize -copy %%f new_%%f` would fun for all jpgs in the dir by replacing %%f with XXX.jpg

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks! I knew it was possible I just didn't know how to approach it. In the code you wrote is the %%f a variable that represents a file in the *.jpg list?

Comment: yep, just `FOR %%f IN (*.JPG) DO echo %%f` to test

Comment: @AlexK. Cool, does every variable have to be preceeded with %%? or can the %%f  be anything? i.e. 'x', 'y', 'file', etc.

Comment: `%%` is needed if you run it in a batch file, you can use any single character for its name. http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html (if you run it from the command line in a console window you need to use single %s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex K.'s answer:

```
FOR %%f IN (*.JPG) DO jpegtran -optimize -copy %%f new_%%f
```

Worked perfectly. This line of code also ran the last command twice, resulting in two files of the last jpeg, but that was a matter of a simple delete and still suits my needs.